# How to show data based on 2 primary keys in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

[image]

[image]

my model in App\Models, I've added the company_id and year to be for the primary key

```
class CompanyMasterCuti extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'company_master_cuti';
    protected $fillable = [
        'company_id', 'year', 'cuti', 'created', 'created_by', 'modified', 'modified_by', 
    ];
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $keyType = 'string';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = ['company_id', 'year'];
    public $incrementing = false;

    public function company() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Company', 'company_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

my code in controller

```
 public function show($company_id, $year) {

        $master_cuti = CompanyMasterCuti::where('company_id', $request->company_id)->where('year', $request->year)->first();

        return view('master-cuti.show', compact('master_cuti'));

    }
```

my code in index.blade.php to direct to route show

```
@forelse($master_cuti as $m_cuti)

  <a href="{{ route('master-cuti.show', [$m_cuti->company_id, $m_cuti->year] ) }}">
          <i class="badge-circle badge-circle-light-secondary bx bxs-show font-medium-1 text-success"></i>
  </a>
@endforelse
```

my code in show.blade.php

```
 <div class="card-content">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <ul class="list-group p-2" style="padding-top: 5px !important">
                                        
                                        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                            <span class="mr-3">Tahun</span>
                                            <span>{{ $master_cuti->year }}</span>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                            <span class="mr-3">Cuti</span>
                                            <span>{{ $master_cuti->cuti}}</span>
                                        </li>

                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

route

```
    Route::resource('master-cuti', CompanyMasterCutiController::class);
```

I want to display data based on company_id and year which is the primary key of the table company_master_cuti . My code is not correct because I tried to return data from the controller the data is null, what's wrong with my code? is there any solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel does not support composite primary keys, check [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#primary-keys). If you want to have a composite primary key you need to do all the work manually.

I would suggest having `id` as the primary key, and define `company_id, year` pair as `unique` key.

You can still ignore `id` as the primary key and use `company_id, year` pair as primary key, but as I mentioned that would be manual work. Check out routing and controller changes.

```
Route::get('master-cuti/{company_id}/{year}/show', CompanyMasterCutiController::class)->name('master-cuti.show');
```

```
 public function show($company_id, $year) {

        $master_cuti = CompanyMasterCuti::where('company_id', $company_id)->where('year', $year)->first();

        return view('master-cuti.show', compact('master_cuti'));

    }
```

Comment: okay I'll try, thanks for the help